# TextAreaField using WT Forms

Tags: flask, textarea, flask-wtforms, wtforms

I am using wt forms to retrieve data from db and display it in frontend. But wt form is displaying data only for first few columns after that it is not displaying data.

FORM

```
class TimesheetEntryForm(Form):
    day = StringField('Day', validators=[Optional()])
    date = DateField('Date', validators=[DataRequired()])
    description = TextAreaField('Description', default='None', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=100)])
    for_act = SelectField('Forecast / Actual', choices=[('F', 'F'), ('A', 'A')], default='A', validators=[DataRequired()])
    dev_hr = IntegerField('Hours spent on Development', default=0, validators=[Optional()])
    prod_hr = IntegerField('Hours spent on Production Support', default=0, validators=[Optional()])
    test_hr = IntegerField('Hours spent on Testing', default=0, validators=[Optional()])
    meet_hr = IntegerField('Hours spent on Meetings', default=0, validators=[Optional()])
    total_hr = IntegerField('Total Hours', default=0, validators=[Optional()])

class TimesheetForm(FlaskForm):
    emp_id = StringField('Employee ID', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=10)])
    project_id = StringField('Project ID', validators=[DataRequired(), Length(max=10)])
    entries = FieldList(FormField(TimesheetEntryForm))
```

FUNCTION

```
@app.route('/edit_timesheet/<year_month>', methods = ['GET', 'POST'])
@csrf.exempt
def edit_timesheet(year_month):

    user_id = session.get('user_id')
    year, month = year_month.split('-')


    # Retrieve data from the database
    conn = db.engine.execute(
        db.select([
            Timesheet.emp_id,
            Timesheet.project_id,
            db.select([text('DATE_FORMAT(date, "%W")')]).label('day'),
            Timesheet.date,
            Timesheet.description,
            Timesheet.for_act,
            Timesheet.dev_hr,
            Timesheet.prod_hr,
            Timesheet.test_hr,
            Timesheet.meet_hr,
            Timesheet.total_hr
        ]).where(
            db.and_(
                Timesheet.emp_id == user_id,
                func.DATE_FORMAT(Timesheet.date, "%Y-%M") == year_month
            )
        )
    ).all()


    conn_1 = db.session.query(
            Employee.first_name + ' ' + Employee.last_name,
            Project.p_name,
            Manager.first_name + ' ' + Manager.last_name,
            Employee.client_manager
        ).join(
            Manager, Employee.manager_id == Manager.m_id
        ).join(
            Project, Manager.project_id == Project.p_id
        ).filter(
            Employee.e_id == user_id
        ).all()

    rows = conn
    rows_1 = conn_1

    dev_hrs = []
    for row in rows:
        dh = row[6]
        dev_hrs.append(dh)


    timesheets = []
    for row in rows:
        form = TimesheetForm()
        form.emp_id.data = row['emp_id']
        form.project_id.data = row['project_id']
        entry = TimesheetEntryForm()
        entry.day.data = row['day']
        entry.date.data = row['date']
        print(entry.date.data)
        entry.description.data = row['description']
        print(entry.description.data)
        entry.for_act.data = row['for_act']
        print(entry.for_act.data)
        entry.dev_hr.data = row['dev_hr']
        print(entry.dev_hr.data)
        entry.prod_hr.data = row['prod_hr']
        entry.test_hr.data = row['test_hr']
        entry.meet_hr.data = row['meet_hr']
        entry.total_hr.data = row['total_hr']

        form.entries.append_entry(entry)
        timesheets.append(form)

    # Calculating hours by category
    dev_sum = 0
    prod_sum = 0
    test_sum = 0
    meet_sum = 0
    total_sum = 0

    # Loop through the data and add up the values for each column
    for row in rows:
        dev_sum += row['dev_hr'] or 0
        prod_sum += row['prod_hr'] or 0
        test_sum += row['test_hr'] or 0
        meet_sum += row['meet_hr'] or 0
        total_sum += row['total_hr'] or 0


    sums = [dev_sum, prod_sum, test_sum, meet_sum, total_sum]


    # Calculating percent by category
    dev_per = 0
    prod_per = 0
    test_per = 0
    meet_per = 0
    total_per = 0

    if total_sum != 0:
        dev_per = round((dev_sum/total_sum)*100, 2)
        prod_per = round((prod_sum/total_sum)*100, 2)
        test_per = round((test_sum/total_sum)*100, 2)
        meet_per = round((meet_sum/total_sum)*100, 2)
        total_per = round((total_sum/total_sum)*100, 2)

    percent = [dev_per, prod_per, test_per, meet_per, total_per]

    content = { 'user_id' : user_id,
                'timesheets' : timesheets,
                'rows_1' : rows_1,
                'year_month' : year_month,
                'rows' : rows,
                'month' : month,
                'year' : year,
                'sums' : sums,
                'percent' : percent,
                'dev_hrs' : dev_hrs
            }
    return render_template("edit_timesheet.html", content=content)
```

TEMPLATE

```
{% for form in content.timesheets %}
                            {% for entry in form.entries %}
                            <tr>
                                <td>{{ form.emp_id(class="form-control") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ form.project_id(class="form-control") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.day.data(class="form-control") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.date.data(class="form-control") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.description }}></td>
                                <td>{{ entry.for_act(class="form-control") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.dev_hr(class="form-control") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.prod_hr(class="form-control") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.test_hr(class="form-control") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.meet_hr(class="form-control") }}</td>
                                <td>{{ entry.total_hr(class="form-control") }}</td>
                            </tr>
                            {% endfor %}
                        {% endfor %}
```

if i use `entry.description.data` it gives no error but data is also not being displayed, and error  `TYPEERROR: 'str' is not callable` comes if `entry.description(class="form-control")` and `entry.description.data(class="form-control")` is used

data is being displayed this `entry.date`  after this data is not being displayed.
Can someone let me know where i am wrong.

Comment: I'd be interested to see the full error traceback if you try `entry.description(class="form-control")`?

Comment: @PatrickYoder is this good ??
Error running WSGI application
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
 File "/home/asur/mysite/flask_app.py", line 528, in edit_timesheet
2023-04-20 08:21:53,500:     return render_template("edit_timesheet.html", content=content)
File "/home/asur/mysite/templates/edit_timesheet.html", line 162, in top-level template code
2023-04-20 08:21:53,501:     <td>{{ entry.description(class="form-control") }}</td>

Comment: I believe that error is when you use `entry.description.data`, but if you use `entry.description(class="form-control")`, it should give a different error. If it doesn't, could you edit your question to include the whole traceback?

Comment: @PatrickYoder with entry.description.data(class="form-control") this is the error
Error running WSGI application
2023-04-20 08:21:41,351: jinja2.exceptions.UndefinedError: 'str object' has no attribute 'data'

with entry.description.data no error is coming but data is not being displayed

Comment: If you reduce your code down to the smallest amount possible that still produces the error, I think you can find the solution. Start with taking out as many fields from your forms as possible; you can even remove much of the unrelated code in your `edit_timesheet` route. This should help us narrow down the problem.